# VisualStudio 2017: TypeScript breakpoints doesn't work

Tags: debugging, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Use standard SPA project template for `.NET Core 2`.

```
dotnet new knockout
```

This template is [located here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/rel/2.0.0/templates/KnockoutSpa)
When I run project by `IIS Express`, part of breakpoint is working, but another part is not working. For example, it works for the `Router` class:

```
constructor(history: History.History, routes: Route[]) {
    // Reset and configure Crossroads so it matches routes and updates this.currentRoute
    crossroads.removeAllRoutes(); <- here a breakpoint works
    crossroads.resetState();
```

But doesn't work for `fetch-data.ts` with message "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

```
constructor() {
    fetch('/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts') <-- A breakpont doesn't work
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<WeatherForecast[]>)
        .then(data => {
            this.forecasts(data);
        });
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you visit the /api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts in your browser directly? Generally we use the URL like private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api, whether it was related to the URL in your side?

Comment: ,Would you please share the latest information in your side? What about this issue?